# sqlalchemy select rows ordered by dependency

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a self referencing table like the following:

```
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = "t_employee"

    id = sa.Column(BigInteger, sa.Sequence('%s_id_seq' % __tablename__), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    manager_id = sa.Column(BigInteger, sa.ForeignKey("t_employee.id", ondelete='SET NULL'))
```

I want to select all rows ordered by their dependency (much like metadata.sorted_tables does for tables).
E.g - each manager should come before his employees

Any help is appreciated.